# What does this the DH 2e's Mounted Warrior's 'each advance' mean?

Tags: dark-heresy-2e, warhammer

> Mounted Warrior
>
> Requirements:  Rank 2 (Trained) in any Operate skill or Rank>
> 2(Trained) in Survival skill, BS 30 or WS 30
>
> Apptitude 1 Weapon Skill / Ballistic Skill
>
> Aptitude 2  Offence
>
> Reduces any penalty for making attacks (Melee or Ranged) from a moving
> vehicle or mount by 10 for each advance.

I've not been able to other sources use similar wordings. Does this mean each rank in all operate and survivor skills gives a +10? Is it just the highest ranked of the 4 skills? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mounted Warrior can be taken multiple times.

Whatever text you're using - I suspect probably it is this [DH 2e Quick Reference](https://apps.ajott.io/quickref/character.html) - is not fully reproducing the actual text of the Mounted Warrior talent (it is, after all, a *quick* reference). Unfortunately, in this case the abridged description of the talent does not describe the talent in adequate detail that you can fully understand it from that text alone. As the proper text of the talent from *Enemy Within* explains:

> When a character purchases this talent, he selects the specialisation that matches the characteristic prerequisite and aptitude used in purchase. He then reduces any penalty for making corresponding attacks (Melee or Ranged) from a moving vehicle or mount by 10 for each time the talent has been purchased in that specialisation.

You can purchase the Mounted Warrior talent several times. Each time you purchase it, you must decide whether this purchase applies to Melee or Ranged attacks, and each time the talent has been purchased for a particular specialisation reduces the relevant penalty to a character's attacks by 10. The quick reference doesn't clarify that you have to choose a specialisation when purchasing the talent (unlike most other talents with specialisations, where "(Choose)" has been appended to the talent's name), and when it refers to "each advance", it is indicating that this advance (the talent) can be purchased more than once.

As it works out, it's only worth taking this talent at most twice in a given specialisation, since the maximum penalty described by the rules for attacking from a moving vehicle is -20, if the vehicle has moved at double speed.